# URL Scheme to open specific part of app

Tags: ios, url-scheme, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an application which can show user-created countdowns.

I have a Today extension widget which shows a few of the user's countdowns and when you tap one, it opens the app and jumps to the view controller for that specific countdown.

I've implemented this via URL scheme. When I tap on a countdown in the widget, it uses the url scheme to open the app. In `application(_: open: options:)`, the app delegate:

- Gets the countdown's UUID from the opened URL
- Gets the index of the countdown object with that ID in the main view controller's array of countdowns (or returns false if it can't find a countdown with that ID)
- Calls `dismiss(animated: false)` on the main view controller to get rid of any presented view controllers
- Calls `popToRootViewController(animated: false)` on the main view controller's navigation controller
- Performs a segue that shows the countdown

This all works great. When I tap a countdown in the widget (or even just type in the URL with a known UUID in Safari) then the app opens up straight to the right countdown.

But it only works if the app was already suspended in the background. If the app isn't open yet, it just opens the app like normal, I guess because the main view controller isn't loaded yet when the app is told to open the URL. How can I get around this? Is there a different or better way I should be implementing this?

Comment: Your code in `application(_: open: options:)` needs to load the proper screens to handle either case.

Comment: What would be the best way to do that then?